# Change time format within JSON code (for AmCharts)

Tags: javascript, json, datetime, format, amcharts

I am making a chart using AmCharts. This is my `stocklegend` section.

```
"stockLegend": {
"valueTextRegular": "[[time]]:[[value]]"
}
```

(Here, time is Date obj converted from timestamp that was present in json dataset loaded in javascript object used as data provider for chart. `"dataProvider": consChartData.Data` where Data is an array holding value & time for a data point.)

Using `[[time]]:[[value]]`, what I am getting is this:

[image]

The way I want it is like: **Dec 23 2017, 5:21:00 IST: 17,686.54**. Is there any way to format the [[time]] here in the way I want?

### Edit

This question was not solved by [How to format a JavaScript date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date) because, if I use that here, it would be like `"valueTextRegular":dateFormat("[[time]]") + "[[value]]",`. I have to make a new Date object from passed time and then it shows:

> "NaN undefined NaN 17,686.54"

in output.

Comment: No. If I use that here, it would be like "valueTextRegular":dateFormat("[[time]]") + "[[value]]", I have to make a new Date object from passed time and then it shows "NaN undefined NaN 17,686.54" in output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use StockLegend's [valueFunction](https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptstockchart/StockLegend#valueFunction) to format the date:

```
"valueFunction": function (panel, value) {

    var category = panel.category;

    if (category && category instanceof Date) {
        // Dec 23 2017, 5:21:00 IST: 17,686.54
        return [AmCharts.formatDate(category, "MMM D YYYY, H:N:SS"), " IST: ", panel.dataContext.value].join("");
    }

    return value;
}
```

Please check the links below:

- [Formatting dates with AmCharts](https://www.amcharts.com/kbase/formatting-dates/)
- [AmCharts Date format helper](https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptstockchart/AmCharts#formatDate)
- [Example](https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/94d25db958d9b04535ec81fe82357757?editors=0010)